# Issue with area route in Asp.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Inside my application I appear to have an issue with my route.  I cannot determine why the route would be failing.  The solution contains a controller that derives from the `[ApiController]` to adhere to Web Api standards.

```
Area > > > Devices > > > Sampler (Controller)
/api/Devices/Sampler/GetSamples/1
{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}
```

My notion that the third line template would correlate representing the first and second line when `MapAreaRoute` is utilized.

```
application.UseMvc(routes =>
{
     routes.MapAreaRoute(
          name: "Device Route",
          areaName: "Devices",
          template: "api/{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}
     );
}
```

Even if I remove `api` from template, specify the area, controller, and action I still receive a 404.

```
[ApiController]
[Area("Devices")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SamplerController : ControllerBase
{
     [HttpGet("{id}")]
     public JsonResult GetSamples(Guid id) => new JsonResult("...");
}
```

Could someone elaborate on why the area does not work?  If I create a directory called Controllers, then use `MapRoute` with the same above code the route works as intended.

Comment: Do you also have a default MapRoute?

Comment: @rad I do not at the moment, as I am hoping to make this the default.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the area this controller belongs in by using an attribute [per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.2#associate-the-controller-with-an-area).

```
    [Area("Products")]
    public class ManageController : Controller
```

Update:
Also you defined `api/{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}` as your route and per your comment you are trying `api/devices/sampler/8`. So using your route as a guide your URL should be `api/devices/sampler/GetSamples/8`. You need to include the action name in the url since that is how its laid out in your route: `api/{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}`

Comment: Can you share the URL you are using? Hard to give you more help without sharing that.

Comment: I posted above, I’d like to do api/devices/sampler/8

Comment: Appreciate the update, I forgot to add the `GetSampler` that was my fault.  But that should exists.  Really I want to use `api/devices/sampler/getsampler/8` which does not work still.  Where if I do the default route, without `MapAreaRoute` I can make it work.